# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM#### index.html:1:11)

Tags: javascript

First of all, sorry for my bad english. Not a native speaker.
I'm having issues getting a product (brought in by using fetch) added to my cart.
When I click on the button, my console says the following:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ${product.id} is not defined
> at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM#### index.html:1:11)

${product.id} being the ID of the respective product, and each # being a number.

This is all of the code:

```js
let products = [];


// GENERATE PRODUCT CARDS
const generateCards = (arrayFiltered) => {
    let generatorCards = ``;
    arrayFiltered.forEach((product) => {
        generatorCards += `    <div class="card-responsive col mb-5">
    <div class="card h-100">
        <!-- Product image-->
        <img class="card-img-top" src="${product.thumbnail}" alt="..." />
        <!-- Product details-->
        <div class="card-body p-4">
            <div class="text-center">
                <!-- Product name-->
                <h5 class="fw-bolder">${product.title}</h5>
                <!-- Product price-->
                $${product.price}
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Product actions-->
        <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
            <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto mb-2 btn_add-cart" href="#" onclick="addToCart(${product.id})">Agregar al carrito</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`;
    })
    document.getElementById('container-products').innerHTML = generatorCards;
};


// ADD TO CART FUNCTION
const addToCart = (productId) => {
    const foundIndex = products.findIndex(product => product.id == productId);
        cart.push(products[foundIndex]);
        Toastify({
            text: "El producto fue agregado al carrito exitosamente! :D",
            duration: 2500,
        }).showToast();
        cartReduce();
};


// FECTH
API_URL = 'https://api.mercadolibre.com'
API_ENDPOINT_SEARCH_NICKNAME = '/sites/MLA/search?nickname='
const fetchDataBase = () => {
    fetch(API_URL + API_ENDPOINT_SEARCH_NICKNAME + 'FVENTAS+ONCE')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            products = products.concat(data.results);
            console.log(data);
            generateCards(products);
        })
}

fetchDataBase();
```

```html
<section>
        <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5 mt-5">
            <div id="container-products"
                class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-3 row-cols-xl-4 justify-content-center">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

PLEASE, HELP! IT'S FOR A FINAL PROJECT IN JAVASCRIPT!
Thanks so much in advance!

If you want to see the full page up and running to have a better understanding of my problem, here's the link to the running GitHub page:

https://palvyg.github.io/proyecto-javascript/

Comment: The problem is caused by doing something bad: composing HTML strings. You have `onclick="addToCart(${product.id})"` which produces `onclick="addToCart(someID)"` however what you want is `onclick="addToCart('${product.id}')"` instead so you'll get `onclick="addToCart('someID')"`. Still, again, l this is very bad practice. You should create the link as element, add it to the dom, then add an event listener to it. Inline code is bad.

Comment: ChrisG, thanks a LOT! that solved my problem! I know it's a bad practice, but for the final project they are making us utilize bad form and proper form, I already learnt and included the correct way: adding it to the DOM. Thanks for your trouble!

Answer (score -1):

The answer was posted by ChrisG on a comment. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).